# java concurrency in practice 5.19

Tags: java, concurrency

In JCIP book, Listing 5.19 Final Implementation of Memorizer. My questions are:

1. The endless while loop is here because of atomic putIfAbsent()?
2. should the while loop just inside impl of putIfAbsent() instead of client code?
3. should the while loop be in smaller scope just wrapping putIfAbsent()?
4. while loop looks bad on readability

Code:

```
public class Memorizer<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {
    private final ConcurrentMap<A, Future<V>> cache
            = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();
    private final Computable<A, V> c;
    public Memorizer(Computable<A, V> c) { this.c = c; }
    public V compute(final A arg) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) { //<==== WHY?
        Future<V> f = cache.get(arg);
        if (f == null) {
           Callable<V> eval = new Callable<V>() {
               public V call() throws InterruptedException {
                    return c.compute(arg);
               }
           };
           FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);
           f = cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);
           if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); }
        }
        try {
           return f.get();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
           cache.remove(arg, f);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
           throw launderThrowable(e.getCause());
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: other than the while question answered here, I am wondering why the following code is necessary:  if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); } for the reasons:
1. the immediate previous code is not supposed to return null
2. there is another if (f == null) already present ahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) The endless while loop is here because of atomic putIfAbsent()?

The while loop here is for repeating computation when a computation was cancelled (first case in `try`).

> 2) Should the while loop just inside impl of putIfAbsent() instead of client code?

No, please, read what `putIfAbsent` does. It just tries to put an object once only.

> 3) Should the while loop be in smaller scope just wrapping putIfAbsent()?

No, it shouldn't. See #1.

> 4) While loop looks bad on readability.

You are free to offer something better. In fact, this construction suites perfect for situation when you have to try to do something until it proceeds successfully.

Comment: You are right. My question 2,3,4 are followups if Q1 is true. Of course, Q1 is not true, so all followup are invalid.

Comment: other than the while question answered here, I am wondering why the following code is necessary:  if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); } for the reasons:
1. the immediate previous code is not supposed to return null
2. there is another if (f == null) already present ahead

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot reduce the scope of the while loop. You want to do `f.get()` on the value that is in the cache. If there was no value for `arg` in the map, you want to execute `get()` on your result, otherwise you want to get the existing value for `arg` in the map and `get()` that one.

The problem is that there are no locks in this implementation, so between you checking if there is a value and trying to insert a value, another thread could have inserted its own value. Equally, it could be the case that between the insertion failing and the retrieval, the value could have been removed from the cache (due to an `CancellationException`). Because of these failure cases, you spin in the `while(true)` until either you can get the canonical value out of the map or you insert a new value into the map (making your value canonical).

It would seem that you could try to more the `f.get()` out of the loop, but that is kept in due to the risk of an `CancellationException`, where you want to keep trying.

Comment: Thanks. I think while loop only works for CancellationException not ExecutionException as launderThrowable just rethrow ExecutionException out of scope.

Comment: @ying Yep, put in the wrong exception name. Why it is a bad idea to copy and paste code.

Comment: other than the while question answered here, I am wondering why the following code is necessary:  if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); } for the reasons:
1. the immediate previous code is not supposed to return null
2. there is another if (f == null) already present ahead

Comment: @DenisWang The `if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); }` code is there because of the previous line, `f = cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);`. `putIfAbsent` returns null if the key was absent (or mapped to null). `f` is supposed to be the canonical cached value, so if it is `null` before the check, we know that `ft` got into the map as the canonical value. We then execute it and assign it to `f` to return.